# Game prelauncher with configurations (resolution/quality)

Tags: resolution, configuration

I've seen that a lot of games have the exactly same configuration screen before the game launches, as you can see in the following screenshot.

[image: Game configuration]

Is this screen generated by some tool, for example, Unity, GameMaker or anything, or is it a plugin that we can use?

Comment: Maybe it's just me but I really dislike seeing this dialog. The screen resolution never seems to be native at default. The 'Graphics quality' options aren't friendly for more advanced users, and sometimes only offer 1 option. And the input tab is always a mess... </rage>

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The launcher in question is included by default for games built with Unity and is called the resolution dialog.

Currently there is very little customization that can be done to this dialog though preset values can be defined using the [Player Settings.](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettings.html)

Additionally the dialog can be disabled altogether within the player settings using the [ResolutionDialogSetting enum](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ResolutionDialogSetting.html).

> Disabled:  Never show the resolutions dialog.
>
> Enabled:   Show the resolutions dialog on first launch.
>
> HiddenByDefault:   Hide the resolutions dialog on first launch.

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on the actual toolset that's been used in creating some game. There's no such standard screen built into Windows or anything like that. If you see the same window in two different games, then either both use similar/same ressources or one has been modelled after the other.

Are there such plugins or libraries available? Most likely, but listing them here would most likely be considered off-topic/out of scope (since there's no definitive answer to that).

However, in general, I'd try to avoid such setup screens. They're only quite popular in games that have been ported from consoles to PCs or games where the creator isn't supposed having to fiddle around with them (systems like RPG Maker or GameStudio etc.).

They might make writing the program easier (since you no longer have to worry about changeable settings while the game is running), but at the same time it limits the user's ability to adjust settings on the fly, which might also be considered negative.

Comment: Your answer has a good point. I've never thought of those screens as being negative in any way before reading this answer. I was actually thinking about how I love it when games allow me to change the settings before the game starts. That way I don't have to get in the game, change the settings, get a prompt telling me to restart the game, quit the game, wait a bit, start the game again.

Comment: @MiniRagnarok That's one of the advantages of such an approach. Ideally you could have both, but also keep in mind that people don't like having to click through a launcher every time (and it might also avoid people playing your game with gamepad only since they might have to click a button).